# How to cite sources from the same author with conflicting last names?

Tags: citation-style, personal-name

I'm using the APA citation style. The author in question is Spanish. In one paper, he uses the format "John Forbes". In the other, he uses "John Forbes Nash". It feels weird to cite two works from the same author using different last names ("Forbes, J.", and "Nash, J. F.").

Comment: If I correctly understand Spanish names, this author's surname is "Forbes Nash" and so the second citation should be "Forbes Nash, J."

Comment: Is it clear in the John Forbes Nash paper that only Nash is used as the surname and not Forbes Nash together?

Comment: @BryanKrause No. But it looks like he omits his actual last name from most publications. The one with the full name is actually a doctoral dissertation.

Comment: @Wood There's no "actual last name" here.

Answer (score 3):

Official names in Spain and Latin America consists of two last names, one from the father and one from the mother, e.g. Gomez y Sanchez. The latter can be omitted to conform to the prevalent naming scheme in the literature. You adopt APA by using the "first" last name, i.e. Gomez in my example.